# Are there any ways to call database data to provide in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

This is the Test that i have:

```
[Test]
public async Task Late_Test()
{
  var options = new DBContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
  .Options;
  
  using(var context = MyContext(options))
  {
    //Act?
  }
    // Assert?
}
```

This is the service that I am trying to create a test for:

```
public async Task<int> LatesInMin(Model1 model1, bool isbool) 
{
 //code here
}
```

The code int the service also needs the data in the foreign keys attached to Model1.
Can i call a data from the database and use it as the parameter when i call the service? Or do i have to manually provide that data as well? I tried and using linq causes an error and I searched that you cant use extension methods such as 'Where()' and 'FirstOrDefault()'

Comment: It's not clear how you are going to use database data. Is it just for test setup, or database is a dependency of the SUT? The relevant details of your question should be in `Act`, `Assert`, and `code here` sections

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

For your tests to be isolated and predictable, you need to make sure that you set up and tear down anything associated with the tests. Therefore, you should be seeding a data source either with data alongside your test code, or with data in an associated file which is loaded in before each test.
What I'm basically trying to get at is that I think you should pull all of the data you require out of the database, save that into a file somewhere, and then load it in before you run each test.
By "load", you could spin up a real database and save the values, or you could use the `InMemoryDatabase` feature provided by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to use Mocking framework and EntityFramework  to mock the call to the database.

Here is an example straight from the tests:

```
  [TestClass]
  public class DbContextTests
  {
   public class Person
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public class DbContextOne : DbContext
   {
     public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
   }

  [TestMethod]
  public void Prepare_ShouldAssignDbSetProperties()
  {
    var dbContext = EntityFrameworkMock.Create<DbContextOne>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(dbContext.People);
  }
  }
```

In the above example I create a mock of my DbContext-deriving class. As a result, all fields that are of type DbSet or IDbSet are automatically populated with a mock in-memory DbSet (initially empty).
We can also create a mock from a DbContext-like interface, like in the example below:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
IDbSet<Person> People { get; }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Prepare_Interface_DbSetsInitialized()
{
var dbContext = EntityFrameworkMock.Create<IMyDbContext>();
Assert.IsNotNull(dbContext.People);
}
```

You can look into this articles for example which shows how use JustMock tool to fake collections https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/justmock/advanced-usage/entity-framework-mocking.html and https://github.com/telerik/JustMock.EntityFramework